# How to create an intent which should act as followup intent and as well main intent which can be triggered directly in Dialog Flow?

Tags: android, dialog, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

if i want to create an intent for favorites then.
   if user asks "what are his favorites" and it will display some suggestion chips 
 so it invokes any follow up intent concerned with that chip. 
    Favorite drink
    favorite food
    favorite films etc.

i also want to invoke directly an "favorite Drink" directly without even asking about main intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use Followup Intents. If you're expecting the user to be able to say something at any time - go ahead and make it a top-level Intent.

Followup Intents should be used rarely, if ever. Mostly they're good for responses that should only happen right after very specific prompts triggered by an Intent: Things like "yes" and "no" responses to a question, for example. Even these could be good top-level Intents, however, if you manage them with Contexts or other state.

Most of all, remember that Intents capture *what the user says*, and doesn't reflect on *how you handle that*.

Answer (score -1):

multiple intents - one to show the options to the user possibly by using helpers and second intent will have an event to catch the selected option by putting "actions_intent_OPTION" in the events section in the Dialogflow.

Comment: welcome to stack you may want to read [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)